# Line-shift report, Line-day report

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, report

I'm generating a line-shift report:

In my application, I'm providing a dropdownlist for selecting shift and line and they will select a date from calender

I have 3 shifts

- shift1 starts at 7am and ends at 3pm
- shift2 starts at 3pm and ends at 11pm
- shift3 starts at 11pm and ends at 3am

I have a table called `datalogging` where login information will be stored as shown below:

```
Name       Shiftname       ID          operatorname   Date           plantname    line     Machine
Pradeepa  Shift2(11-7)     3           Operator 3     2011-05-28     Plant 3      Line5    mc10
Ashwini   Shift1(7-3)      1           Operator 1     2011-05-29     Plant 3      Line6    mc12
Deepika   Shift2(11-7)     2           Operator 3     2011-05-29     Plant 5      Line9    mc18
Ashwini   Shift1(7-3)      1           Operator 1     2011-05-24     Plant 1      Line1    mc1
Deepika   Shift2(3-11)     2           Operator 2     2011-05-24     Plant 2      Line3    mc5
Ashwini   Shift2(3-11)     1           Operator 2     2011-05-25     Plant 2      Line3    mc5
```

and so on..

I have a parameter table like temperature,pressure,ph,speed,co2 etc

`Temperature` table contains following data and this table will contains all the reading from 7am to till 3am

```
Temperature      Time              Date
27               13:13:54.000      2011-05-25
27.3             13:14:04.000      2011-05-25 
27.6             13:14:14.000      2011-05-25 
27.9             13:14:24.000      2011-05-25
28.2             13:14:34.000      2011-05-25 
28.5             13:14:44.000      2011-05-25 
27               16:13:29.000      2011-05-26 
27               16:13:31.000      2011-05-26
```

and so on..

The user will select a line from dropdownlist and shift and he will select a date from th calender
If the user select shift2,line3 and date 25/05/2011 what are the readings are there between 3pm to 11pm should be displayed in my report

My report should look like:

```
Machine     Shiftname   Date               Time             Temperature
mc5         Shift2      25/05/2011         13:13:54.000     27
mc5         Shift2      25/05/2011         13:14:04.000     27.3
mc5         Shift2      25/05/2011         13:14:14.000     27.6
```

I'm also doing line-day report

where shiftname should change according to time for eg if time changes to 23:00:00 shiftname should change to shift3 in my report

if the user select particular shift and date for eg if the user selects shift1,line1 and date my report should contain all reading between 7am to 3pm

can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your report with following query

```
SELECT d.Machine
       , CASE WHEN t.time BETWEEN '19:00:00.000' AND '23:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift1'
              WHEN t.time BETWEEN '00:00:00.000' AND '02:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift1'
              WHEN t.time BETWEEN '03:00:00.000' AND '10:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift2'
              WHEN t.time BETWEEN '11:00:00.000' AND '18:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift3'
          END
       , t.Date
       , t.Time
       , t.Temperature
FROM   Datalogging d
       INNER JOIN Temperature t ON t.Date = d.Date
WHERE  d.Shifname = 'Shift2(3-11)'
       AND d.Line = 'Line3'
       AND t.Date = '25/05/2011'
```

but if we can assume that each machine would have temperature readings each day, it is clear that there's a relationship missing between your `Temperature` and `Datalogging` table.

Comment: @lieven:how to change shiftname if time changes like if time chaged to 23:00:00 shiftname should chage

Comment: @Sweety, with your given table structure, you don't have to. The shiftname is included in the `DataLogging` table. But as I said, I think you are either not showing us the complete table definitions or you are missing a relationship.

Comment: @Sweety, I have changed the answer but you should note that *if* this solves your question, it is my firm belief that your data relations are not entirely correct.

Comment: @lieven:when i'm exporting this gridview data to excel sheet the data is not displaying in the excel sheet can u help me on that..

Comment: @Sweety - I assume that's a `c# (.net)` related problem?! I have done *some* `c#` programming but that is really outside my area of expertice.

Comment: @lieven:im gettng error its showing Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.